# IBM ODM UI model for json comparision

Tags: websphere, ibm-odm

I have a requirement in which i get two json file in request and I need to copare two json files.
Is there a way within ODM where  can show customers the UI for text comparision of json ?

Lets say, json 1 file has a field name which is different from json2 name. I need to show with any report /Ui that this is the difference between two files.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question with regard to the environment you expect to execute ODM? Is ODM executed within a server-based environment? Is ODM to be embedded in some other Java program?

Answer (score 0):

The ODM user interfaces, either Eclipse-base *Rule Designer* or web-based *Decision Center*, allow extensive customization, but these UI's are for authoring the rules, not applying them to input data.

ODM rules are generally run within a server environment, so at execution time there is no user or user interface. It is possible (and feasible and reasonable) to embed ODM execution into any Java program (for example, one with a UI to show or compare differences between JSON document), but ODM does not provide any kind of UI framework for building such a program.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and used [JsonAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) library to compare Jsons in Java.

Best
Emmanuel